# If space is a vacuum, why is the moon said to be so dusty?

Tags: vacuum, space

Can't vacuums suck up dust?

Also where did the dust come from? I heard most dust is particles of human skin.

Comment: House dust is not moon dust. Nature blows from higher pressure to lower pressure. It does not suck. Also you might want to state your background here...the questions you asked haven't been thought through very well and might draw different undeserved ire if you're in grade school compared to if you're in university, for example.

Answer (score 4):

> Can't vacuums suck up dust?

No. A vacuum cannot suck up dust. A vacuum cleaner sucks up dust, but it does so using air, not vacuum.

> Also where did the dust come from? I heard most dust is particles of human skin.

The dust on the moon comes from meteor impacts on the moon that smash the lunar rocks into small fragments. It is rock, not skin.

Comment: You tell 'em, dale! +1 -NN